# how can i retrive data from database and display it in a Select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display into the Select the response of the query mostraReferti, so I can display the list of items from the dropdown menu.

This is the response I get from the query:

response:

```
[
  {
    hash_referto: "e9cceea77b26d2090649a923116a35882088d23378b0ad10ff48d139ae3db1da",
    proprietario: "050708",
    public_key: "0x7343197ba6ee64b5f07322ce1acb0f8f29897689",
    data_esame: "2019-08-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    tipo_esame: "urologia",
    uri: null
  },
  {
    hash_referto: "5bad691600ade15abc5949ba8b089e0699071b72e503364fd0e05438a4b4581d",
    proprietario: "230888",
    public_key: "0x9628ade5057141a66018b63b78cbdc4a44f055b2",
    data_esame: "2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    tipo_esame: "pediatra",
    uri: null
  },
  {
    hash_referto: "codiceReferto",
    proprietario: "230888",
    public_key: "0x9628ade5057141a66018b63b78cbdc4a44f055b2",
    data_esame: "2019-10-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    tipo_esame: "dentista",
    uri: null
  }
];
```

it would be nice to display only "data esame" and "tipo esame"

Here's the code:

```
class CredentialsPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allowToProceed: false,
      email: "",
      receiverCode: "",
      initialDate: "",
      expireDate: "",
      rights: "",
      codiceReferto: null,
      nextBtnDisabled: true,
      careGiver: "",
      value: "",
      id: "",
      referti: {}
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;

    requestAccountAccess(defaultAccount => {
      actions.account.setDefaultAccount(defaultAccount);
      actions.contract.setContract(defaultAccount);
    });

    mostraReferti(this.state.id);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const { account } = nextProps;
    return { id: account.id };
  }

  onEnter = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      const { allowToProceed } = this.state;
      if (allowToProceed) {
        this.proceed();
      }
    }
  };

  proceed = () => {
    const { actions, history } = this.props;
    const { codiceReferto, id } = this.state;

    actions.account.setCodiceReferto(codiceReferto);
    history.push("/consenso?panel=2");
  };

  enableNext = input => {
    const {} = this.props;
    if (input.valid) {
      this.setState({
        allowToProceed: true,
        email: input.value,
        nextBtnDisabled: false
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { id, nextBtnDisabled } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles}>
        <h2>Compila i campi per assegnare un consenso</h2>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-section">
            <div className="custom-select">
              <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
              <select
                name="codiceReferto"
                placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
                onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
                value={this.codiceReferto}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              >
                <option default value="vuoto"></option>
                <option value="ciao">Display items</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />

            <br />

            <Label text="Il tuo Account ID (da MetaMask)" />
            <Input type="text" readOnly value={id} />
          </div>
        </Form>

        <Controls
          prevDisabled
          nextDisabled={nextBtnDisabled}
          handleNext={this.proceed}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mostraReferti(id) {
  console.log("id", id);
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/" + id).then(response => {
    console.log("response " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
    return response.data;
  });
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: state.account,
    asset: state.asset
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      account: bindActionCreators(accountActionCreators, dispatch),
      contract: bindActionCreators(contractActionCreators, dispatch)
    }
  };
}

CredentialsPanel.propTypes = {
  account: PropTypes.shape({
    email: PropTypes.string,
    receiverCode: PropTypes.string,
    initialDate: PropTypes.date,
    expireDate: PropTypes.date,
    rights: PropTypes.string,
    codiceReferto: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  asset: PropTypes.shape({}),
  history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired
};

CredentialsPanel.defaultProps = {
  asset: null
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CredentialsPanel))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you ran into?

Comment: the problem is that i'm not able to set the state of "referti" . i Tried to add  
 this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        }) .   but it gives and error "setState is not defined"

Comment: so where exactly have you used this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => { console.log(this.state); }).

Comment: function mostraReferti(id) {
  console.log("id", id)
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/' + id)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("response1" + JSON.stringify(response.data))
     this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        })
      return response.data
    })
  }

Comment: It seems that you are have used this code inside the mostraReferti() function. In this case the setState() wont work because setState() only works inside the class Component , and the function is defined outside the class. So instead of defining that function outside the class just make it a method of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please move `mostraReferti` method inside component and add the below inside constructor?

```
this.mostraReferti = this.mostraReferti.bind(this);
```

Final code:

```
class CredentialsPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allowToProceed: false,
      email: "",
      receiverCode: "",
      initialDate: "",
      expireDate: "",
      rights: "",
      codiceReferto: null,
      nextBtnDisabled: true,
      careGiver: "",
      value: "",
      id: "",
      referti: {}
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.mostraReferti = this.mostraReferti.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;

    requestAccountAccess(defaultAccount => {
      actions.account.setDefaultAccount(defaultAccount);
      actions.contract.setContract(defaultAccount);
    });

    mostraReferti(this.state.id);
  }

  mostraReferti(id) {
      console.log("id", id);
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/" + id).then(response => {
        console.log("response " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return response.data;
      });
    }


  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const { account } = nextProps;
    return { id: account.id };
  }

  onEnter = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      const { allowToProceed } = this.state;
      if (allowToProceed) {
        this.proceed();
      }
    }
  };

  proceed = () => {
    const { actions, history } = this.props;
    const { codiceReferto, id } = this.state;

    actions.account.setCodiceReferto(codiceReferto);
    history.push("/consenso?panel=2");
  };

  enableNext = input => {
    const {} = this.props;
    if (input.valid) {
      this.setState({
        allowToProceed: true,
        email: input.value,
        nextBtnDisabled: false
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { id, nextBtnDisabled } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={styles}>
        <h2>Compila i campi per assegnare un consenso</h2>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-section">
            <div className="custom-select">
              <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
              <select
                name="codiceReferto"
                placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
                onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
                value={this.codiceReferto}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              >
                <option default value="vuoto"></option>
                <option value="ciao">Display items</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />

            <br />

            <Label text="Il tuo Account ID (da MetaMask)" />
            <Input type="text" readOnly value={id} />
          </div>
        </Form>

        <Controls
          prevDisabled
          nextDisabled={nextBtnDisabled}
          handleNext={this.proceed}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: state.account,
    asset: state.asset
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      account: bindActionCreators(accountActionCreators, dispatch),
      contract: bindActionCreators(contractActionCreators, dispatch)
    }
  };
}

CredentialsPanel.propTypes = {
  account: PropTypes.shape({
    email: PropTypes.string,
    receiverCode: PropTypes.string,
    initialDate: PropTypes.date,
    expireDate: PropTypes.date,
    rights: PropTypes.string,
    codiceReferto: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  asset: PropTypes.shape({}),
  history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired
};

CredentialsPanel.defaultProps = {
  asset: null
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CredentialsPanel))
```